# http_proxy variable

Tags: proxy, environment-variables

I was following this guide to install Redmine on my **server**:
 http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_in_Ubuntu

it written there:

```
Run the following commands to export your proxy settings for both http (port 80) and https (port 443):

export http_proxy="http://proxy.your.server:port" 
export https_proxy="http:proxy.your.server:port"
```

so i did... and now i can't install things, for example :

```
Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gems/gems_1.1.1-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
```

But if i insert the url address to my browser - i do get the file. 
Not sure there is connection between  the two things.
I would like to know what was my http_proxy before i changed it.

Comment: To clarify, this is not a duplicate question, since the OP's problem is the opposite of that in the proposed duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`http_proxy` and `https_proxy` are, by default, blank. You can run `unset http_proxy https_proxy` to undo your actions.

You should only set a proxy if your PC is actually behind a proxy. If it is, you would already know the proxy details (the hostname and port, and username and password if applicable), and you would therefore replace `http://proxy.your.server:port` with the appropriate details.

Since you can access the internet through your browser without configuring a proxy, I think you probably aren't behind one. Therefore, you can just unset the variables as described initially and proceed with the rest of the tutorial.

Note that web proxies are common in corporate environments, but it's very uncommon for people to configure proxies in their own homes, and hosted servers won't sit behind web proxies. Proxies are normally used to control access to certain categories of websites (e.g. social media or webmail), or to add a local caching layer, or for malware filtering.

Comment: while that information is accurate, it does not answer the question as you still need to configure apt. see my above link

Comment: Since the OP isn't behind a proxy, they only need to ensure that they do not configure a proxy server. However it's certainly worth making the point that, should one need to configure a proxy, apt needs to be handled separately due to sudo's default configuration.